# when using jstl tag <c:if inside javascript i get error

Tags: java, javascript, html, jstl

When I use the tag:

```
<c:if test="${comment.mediaObject.getClass().name == 'entities.persistent.Photo'}">
```

inside a JavaScript function in a jsp page I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on token "if", ( expected after this token
```

Under html code in .jsp page this works great but not when under JavaScript functions.

What I am trying to do is passing a list of Photos in JavaScript to then pass them to the initialize function that prints them in Google maps. But for that I need to know whether the mediaObjects is of type photo or else I don't do anything.

EDIT:

replacing getClass() with class actually stops the sintax error, although i get the following execution error:

```
message /MapRoutes.jsp (line: 113, column: 4) "${comment.mediaObject.class.name == 'entities.persistent.Photo'}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${comment.mediaObject.class.name == 'entities.persistent.Photo'}]
```

Comment: You should not control the JavaScript code using `<c:if>` nor any other JSTL code. It would be better if you post what you're trying to achieve to get more accurate guidance.

Comment: It seems you are trying to merge two different worlds.

Comment: That it's inside a JS function isn't relevant. If it's in a JS *file*, then it won't be processed by the JSP compiler.

Comment: but <c:forEach tag does. the javascript function is inside.jsp file

Answer (score 1):

Change `comment.mediaObject.getClass().name` to `comment.mediaObject.class.name`.

When your JSP is compiled it will translate to `comment.getMediaObject().getClass().getName()`.

The fact that it's inside a JavaScript block has nothing to do with the error.

EDIT to address the invalid expression:

A little searching shows that certain containers and/or EL specs require the following syntax due to the fact that `class` is a reserved keyword.

```
comment.mediaObject['class'].name
```

A final option is to add the following startup paramater. I'd recommend only doing this if nothing else works since it makes your application less portable.

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Comment: in fact it stopped giving me the error althouth when i run it i get an error. pls check my edited question